# Draw a histogram of a distribution with a discrete component

Tags: python, visualization, distribution, histogram, data-visualization

I'm performing a simulation of a simple queue using `SimPy`. One of the questions about the system is what is the distribution of the waiting times by a visitor. What I do is draw a normalized histogram of the sample I get during the simulation process.

[image: Simply using the histogram plot]

This distribution is not purely continuous, we have a non-zero probability of the waiting time being exactly zero, hence the peak near the left end. I want it to be somehow **obvious** from the picture, **what is the actual probability of hitting `0` exactly**. Right now the height of the peak does not visualize that properly, the height is even higher than one (the reason is that many points are hitting a small segment near zero).

So the question is the general visualization technique of such distributions that are mixtures of a continuous and a discrete one.

Comment: Not sure if there's a general technique per se, but a trivial thing to do would be to include an inset to the plot you're showing with the zoom-in of the region around zero.

Comment: zooming in doesn't help as if while zooming in I will increase the number of bins in the hist, the height of the peak will grow and grow. So the thing is that I need to show the exact probability of hitting zero (the fraction of elements that are equal to zero) and at the same time remove this peak, but not to change other parts of the histogram (simply filtering zeroes out will increase all the bars a bit).

Comment: Why not leaving the main plot as is, and on an inset use the discrete scale of just 0,1,2... with exact probabilities on the y-axis?

Comment: Because it's a mixture of a continuous distribution and a discrete one, it's not a discrete distribution, probability to hit exactly 2 is zero, it's non-zero only for '0' (sorry for a bit of tautology), so I want this diagram to be nice and smooth for `x > 0` but at the same time to show the exact probability of hitting zero.

Comment: So the weighting time is continuous, but the distribution has a delta-function peak at zero, is it? Then what I'd do, I'd plot a histogram of waiting times for `t>0` (technically: start at small enough t), and superimpose the peak at exactly zero, in a different color, with it's own vertical scale (e.g. a right-hand side `y` axis) if desired.

Comment: @Zhenya, (technically: start at small enough t) that is not enough since this will change the actual histogram for `t>0`, but I get the idea. Actually my question was about the general case, not only having peaks at zero, but maybe at other points. I will probably go with the `cdf` actually.

Comment: OK, to avoid burying this into comments, I'll make it a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(based on the discussion in the comments to OP).

For a distribution of some variable, call it `t`, being a mixture of a discrete and and continuous components, I'd write the pdf a sum of a set of delta-peaks and a continuous part,

`p(t) = \sum_{a} p_a \delta(t-t_a) + f(t)`

where `a` enumerates the discrete values `t_a` and `p_a` are probabilities of `t_a`, and `f(t)` is the pdf for the continuous part of the distribution, so that `f(t)dt` is the probability for `t` to belong to `[t,t+dt)`.

Notice that the whole thing is normalized, `\int p(t) =1` where the integral is over the approprite range of `t`.

Now, for visualizing this, I'd separate the discrete components, and plot them as discrete values (either as narrow bins or as points with droplines etc). Then for the rest, I'd use the histogram where you know the correct normalization from the equation above: the area under the histogram should sum up to `1-\sum_a p_a`.

I'm not claiming this being *the* way, it's just what I'd do.

Comment: so I have to know the `t_a`s a priori?

Comment: Let me put it this way: if you know `t_a`s, here's my suggestion for how to visualize the distribution (which is my understanding of the original question). How to find `t_a` is a separate question, which, I suspect, strongly depends on the details of the problem and there are cases where the problem is simply not well defined in purely mathematical terms.